# In naive set theory ∅ = {∅} = {{∅}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

In naive set theory, I believe ∅ = {∅} = {{∅}} is correct, but just wanted to make sure that I understood this correctly.

∅ is an empty set, so having an empty set as an element of a set that contains nothing else is pretty much the same thing as e.g. marking the number 2 as 2.000000, right? Doesn't the symbol ∅ intrinsically imply that this is an empty set which contains it self?

Comment: Somewhat related: [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/19535/8297), [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65600/8297) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51752/8297).

Comment: It may help to think of a set as being like a piece of paper with stuff written on it. ∅ is a blank sheet of paper. {∅} is a sheet of paper that has "∅" written on it. {{∅}} is a sheet of paper that has "{∅}" written on it.

Comment: You should have made your comment an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, it is incorrect.

- `∅` is the empty set.
- `{∅}` is a set, containing exactly one item: The empty set.
- `{{∅}}` is a set, containing exactly one item: A set with one item, which is the empty set.

> Doesn't the symbol ∅ intrinsically imply that this is an empty set which contains it self?

You're confusing two things here: set membership and subsets:

1. ∅ is a subset of **every** set
2. but it is **not** a member of every set, just like `1` is not a member of every set either

**Example**

If you have two items, `a` and `b`, and you are to construct the set of all possible combinations, choosing 0 to all items, this will be your solution:

> {∅, {a}, {b}, {a, b}}

Naturally, every possible combination is represented by a set, that contains the chosen items. And the set of all possible combinations is (obviously) represented by a set containing all those combinations (i.e. sets), now we have a set of sets.

- We can choose no item at all: `∅` is part of our solution
- We can choose one item: `{a}` and `{b}` are part of the solution
- We can choose both items: `{a, b}`

Note: This is called the power set of `{a, b}`, usually denoted `P({a, b})`.

Maybe you think of ∅ as "nothing", because it's empty. However, that's quite far from the truth, an empty set is very "real", it's *not* nothing. You wouldn't say an empty glass is nothing, would you?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the same

**•** ∅ represents the empty set.

**•** {∅} Is a non-empty set. It contains one element. That element is the empty set

**•** {{∅}} This set contains one element. Such element is the set containing the empty set.

Another analogy that might me useful is to think of set as bags. {∅} would represent an empty bag and {{∅}} would represent a bag containing an empty bag

Comment: Your bag analogy is one bag short. $\emptyset $ being the empty set is already one bag, so $\{\emptyset\}$ is a bag containing an empty bag, and so on.